# Winston event logging - can't add listener to default logger

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using winston to log on nodejs and I am configuring the global logger to be used in my project. When I try to attach event handlers to the default logger, I run into problems.

```
winston.on('logging', function (transport, level, msg, meta) {
  console.log('logged');
});
```

This gives me the error: `TypeError: winston.on is not a function`

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method should be used on a winstom instance like

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger);

logger.on('logging', function (transport, level, msg, meta) {
   console.log('logged');
});
```

Comment: I misunderstood winston and thought I could attach listeners to the winston by itself. This is the correct way to handle it.